# How to use dynamic port when port is hard-coded in .json file?

Tags: go, heroku

In attempting to run blue-jay/blueprint from Heroku, I cannot bind to port 80 as specified in the .json file, because Heroku seems to dynamically set the ports.

Using os.Getenv("PORT") does not seem to be an option as the .json is a static file.

**HTTPPort: [env.json](https://github.com/blue-jay/blueprint/blob/master/env.json.example)**

```
"Server": {
    "Hostname": "",
    "UseHTTP": true,
    "UseHTTPS": false,
    "RedirectToHTTPS": false,
    "HTTPPort": 80,
    "HTTPSPort": 443,
    "CertFile": "tls/server.crt",
    "KeyFile": "tls/server.key"
},
```

**Returned server error:**

```
server.go:56: listen tcp :80: bind: permission denied
```

**Sources:**

https://github.com/blue-jay/blueprint/blob/master/env.json.example

https://github.com/blue-jay/blueprint

What is an appropriate way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

True, you cannot set the port on Heroku. You have to deal with their port. I'd recommend to modify `blueprint.go` right before you run the server

```
port := os.Getenv("PORT")

if port == "" {
    log.Fatal("$PORT must be set")
}

config.Server.HTTPPort, _ = strconv.Atoi(port)

// Start the HTTP and HTTPS listeners
server.Run(
    handler,       // HTTP handler
    handler,       // HTTPS handler
    config.Server, // Server settings
)
```

Comment: This feels super close, however, 'config.Server.HTTPPort = port' returns:  "cannot use port (type string) as type int in assignment", presumably from the 'type Info struct' in server.go (HTTPPort int `json:"HTTPPort"`). I tried config.Server.HTTPPort = int(port), and also tried changing the type from int to string within the struct and played around with all sorts of data type conversions, and still get a similar type error. hrm..

Comment: @iamtoc, I see, I've update the code to use strconv.Atoi